# Table is not getting saved in Access using runsql

Tags: ms-access

written query execute successfully without any error but data is not getting saved.
Table_StockList is a Table not sure where i am making mistake . kindly assist.

```
Dim sid As String
Dim pnumber As String
Dim pname As String
Dim pmake As String
Dim pmodel As String
Dim phsn As String
Dim pdop As Date
Dim ppp As Currency
Dim pstatus As String
Dim psp As Currency
Dim paqty As Integer
Dim totalqty As Integer
Dim pinvoice As Attachment


sid = Me.Stock_ID.Value
pnumber = Me.Part_No.Value
pname = Me.Product_Name.Value
pmake = Me.Make.Value
pmodel = Me.Model.Value
phsn = Me.HSN.Value
pdop = Me.curpurchasedate.Value
ppp = Me.Purchase_Price_dr_.Value
pstatus = Me.Status.Value
psp = Me.Selling_price_cr_.Value
paqty = Me.availqty.Value
totalqty = Me.totalqty.Value
pinvoice = Me.Invoice
'Me.Recordset.MoveLast
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Table_StockList ([Stock ID],[Part No],[Product Name],Make,Model,HSN,[Date of Purchase],Status,[Selling price(cr)],[Available QTY],[Total QTY])" & _
"VALUES('" & sid & "','" & pnumber & "','" & pname & "','" & pmake & "','" & pmodel & "','" & phsn & "','" & pdop & "','" & ppp & "','" & pstatus & "','" & psp & "','" & paqty & "','" & totalqty & "','" & pinvoice & "' )"
```

Comment: You need to ensure that the variables are correctly wrapped according to their datatype. Numeric data needs no wrapping, strings need to be wrapping in single quotes, and dates need wrapping in #. You therefore need to remove some of the single quotes, and replace at least one set with #.

Comment: i tried but not sure where i am making mistake .. is it possible for you to edit the given sql query that will help me lot .. since i am not that expert in it. plz.

Comment: The best thing that you can do is to declare a new variable, `Dim strSQL As String`, use this to create the SQL string, and then do `Debug.Print strSQL`. This will give you the SQL statement that is going to be executed. You can then check which values need to be enclosed in single quotes (i.e. the field type is text), which need to be enclosed in hashes (the field type is date), and which need neither (numeric fields).

Comment: sure ... i will try this and share you the output. Thanks for guidance

Comment: i Tried with below steps but it didn't print anything .. strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table_StockList ([Stock ID],[Part No],[Product Name],Make,Model,HSN,[Date of Purchase],Status,[Selling price(cr)],[Available QTY],[Total QTY])" & _
"VALUES('" & sid & "','" & pnumber & "','" & pname & "','" & pmake & "','" & pmodel & "','" & phsn & "','# pdop #','" & ppp & "','" & pstatus & "','" & psp & "','" & paqty & "','" & totalqty & "','" & pinvoice & "' )"

Comment: On the next line, you need `Debug.Print strSQL` to output this to the Immediate Window. You can then see what is trying to be run, and then determine what needs to be enclosed in single quotes or hashes.

Comment: yes that is what when i use debug.print strsql its showing just empty without any value .. its null

Comment: i found issue with attachment & Date format ... if i remove this two then data is getting saved. kindly assist how can write format for a attachment and Date

Comment: The date value needs to be wrapped in #. but not single quotes. So, `, #" & pdop & "#," should work. I've not worked with Attachment datatypes before, so can't help you there.

Comment: Attachment field is handled different from other field types. Attachment is a type of multi-value field. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Data-Access-Objects/work-with-attachments-in-dao